Have + object + Bare Inf
I have a question about the difference between

My boss had me work hard.

and

My boss had me working hard.

Some linguists I talked to previously said that they both mean almost the same, but the former implies an order, while the latter implies some sort of "contraption" being used to make me work hard (meaning that the boss didn't straight up tell me to work hard but maybe cut my salary). Could you please tell me about the difference in meaning and also about whether have + obj + Bare Inf. can have the sense of ordering?

For this American, the version with work means “instructed me, compelled me to work hard,” whereas the working version can mean more like “caused me to be in a situation that involved, perhaps only incidentally, my working hard.” That’s a pretty subtle distinction, but if the intended meaning is along the lines of “issued (and perhaps explicitly enforced) a directive that I work hard,” then I would be much more likely to use your had me work version than your had me working.

@PaulTanenbaum, thank you for your input! Can I please ask if there's any source that can back up your explanation?

I’m afraid I don’t. If I did, I’d have made my remark an answer instead of a comment. What I do have is simply my sense of the two versions’ meanings and how they would likely be used based on 64 years’ experience using English.

I can tell you that The toddler had me running around after him all afternoon means (at least to my ear) that the child was heedless of the trouble I was going to to keep him from harm, whereas The toddler had me run around after him all afternoon means that perhaps he affirmatively enjoyed being chased, but in any case that my pursuit was at his request.
